# How can I monitor hotspot traffic via Charles Proxy?

Tags: charles-proxy

I have a hotspot configured on my laptop and there are multiple devices connected to the hotspot. Using Charles Proxy can I monitor the network traffic from all those devices?

Setting up a proxy configuration is not feasible in those devices. So, I'm looking for a way to monitor all that's happening via my hotspot. Can we somehow make the hotspot work with Charles Proxy?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. Charles can only monitor traffic if the device specifically uses Charles as its proxy. Wireshark may help, but you will struggle with HTTPS traffic.